# Extract lat, lon Points from Polygon

Tags: postgis

I have PostGIS database, and want to extract lat, lon pairs sequence from Polygons (and MultiPolygons). As a very fresh PostGIS user, I'm able to just extract the Polygons:

`SELECT st_astext("GEOMETRY"::geometry) FROM my_postgisdb;`

which outputs Polygons and MultiPoligons.

How should I extract x, y pairs from these structures?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [ST_DumpPoints](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_DumpPoints.html) to get the points and then [ST_AsLatLonText](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_AsLatLonText.html) to get nicely readable coordinate output. It doesn't care if the geometries are multi* or not.

Alternatively, you could use [ST_Boundary](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_Boundary.html) to get the polygon vertices, but you'd need to use `ST_Dump` first for this to work for multipolygons too.

Comment: Can you give a example about how to code it?

Comment: Hi Did you tried the solution?